# Enable basic HttpBinding without SSL in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config

The idea here is that for my testing, before I commit to purchasing the SSL certificate, I want to enable the WCF service in non-ssl mode.  I've done it in the past using this code, but for the life of me, cannot figure out how to translate it into the web.config file.

If someone can put me in the right direction on how you would go about this translation, that would be much appreciated.

```
                Binding basicBinding = null;
                if (RegistryConnectionStringFactory.UseSslForCommunications)
                {
                    basicBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
                    (basicBinding as BasicHttpBinding).Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
                    (basicBinding as BasicHttpBinding).Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;

                    creds.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = UserNamePasswordValidationMode.MembershipProvider;
                    creds.UserNameAuthentication.MembershipProvider = Membership.Provider;
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpTransportBindingElement transport = new HttpTransportBindingElement()
                    {
                        AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Basic
                    };
                    basicBinding = new CustomBinding(transport);

                    svcHost.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = new AspNetUsernamePasswordValidator();
                    svcHost.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your post suggests that want to do this to avoid purchasing an SSL certificate before your testing is complete, I wanted to ask:  To save yourself some time, could you just create your own self-signed certificate using `makecert`?

If so, these notes might be of some help.

To create root certificate key files...

```
makecert  -r -pe -n "CN=My Own Authority,O=My Company,C=US" -ss CA -sr CurrentUser -a sha1 -sky signature -sv mycert.pvk mycert.cer
```

To create a .PFX file...

```
makecert -pe -n "CN=localhost" -a sha1 -sky exchange -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ic mycert.cer -iv mycert.pvk -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 -sv localhost.pvk localhost.cer
pvk2pfx -pvk localhost.pvk -spc localhost.cer -pfx localhost.pfx
```

Then, using the Certificates snap-in, import the `mycert.cer` file into the Trusted Root Certification Authorities on the local computer to tell those apps running on the local machine that any certificate signed by your own authority is trustworty.

Next, you import the `localhost.pfx` file into the Personal store on the local computer.  (Doing this makes the certificate available to IIS so that it may declare itself, by your own authority, to be the server named "localhost".)

There's a detailed descripton of how to import the .PFX file into IIS 7 here:  http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pfx-import-export-iis-7.htm

Comment: I did some further research and found out that companies like Verisign allow you to download test SSL certificates.  http://www.verisign.com/ssl/buy-ssl-certificates/free-ssl-certificate-trial/  I did think about that, but wanted to avoid the headache.  I think doing something like this however may be the best bet.

Comment: P.S.  I'm accepting your answer, partially because it's close to what I'm going to do, and partially so the rest of the community stops beating me up for not accepting answers to questions that don't have a right or wrong answer.

Comment: I'm a little too new here to have yet fully appreciated the importance of having an answer accepted, but I thank you.  In any case, I wish you luck in getting the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with configuration based approach for BasicHttpBinding? You simply use TransportWithMessageCredential and UserName credentials for communication over HTTPS or TransportCredentialOnly and Basic credentials for communication over HTTP.

Comment: Seemed as if when I went that route, it broke forms based authentication for the application itself.

Answer (score 2):

This is an extreme but you can allow anonymous *and* non-SSL by setting the security mode to "none".  Anonymous might also affect your testing so probably not recommended.

```
<binding name="HttpBasicSecurityConfig">
  <security mode="None">
  </security>
</binding>
```

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731172.aspx:

Transport Credentials in Bindings

```
Type   Description
None   Specifies that the client does not need to present any credential. This translates to an anonymous client.
```

Comment: that would be great for something like a twitter api, but this required having a user login.  unfortunately, I had to bag the project due to lack of funding.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at something similar today as well but my knowledge isn't 100% complete.

For the binding you will need to do something like this:

```
   <bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="CustomBinding">
      <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Basic"/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

Then you need to create a serviceBehaviour for the custom validation:

```
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior" >
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseAspNetRoles"roleProviderName="CustomRolesProvider" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication customUserNamePasswordValidatorType ="AspNetUsernamePasswordValidator [Fully qualified name]" userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" />
      </serviceCredentials>
```

obviously not tested but a similar config just worked for me and it may get you started...

Comment: When I did this it seemed to have broke my login abilities to the site.